# Can't get .click() and similar Events working properly

Tags: jquery, events, click

I am heavily stuck at most simple `jQuery` stuff...

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="pic"><img /></div> 
  <div class="pic"><img /></div>
  ...
</div>
```

I am filling the `#wrap` with various images from JSON data,
however, I can't get clicks recognized on by `.pic`

```
$(".pic").click(); $(".pic").on("click", function(){}); $(".pic > img").click(); $("img").click
```

For testing I just add simple *alerts* to the click function and I tried various combinations without any success.
My goal is to feed the ID of the clicked image back to my `JavaScript`.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `.on` doesn't automagically do event delegation, you have to use the correct event delegation syntax. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Can you put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can see the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Check browser's console, you might be having javascript errors stemming from earlier code.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.pic', function() {
    //do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set additional parameter to the `.on()` function to get it respond, **if** the elements are appended dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrap").on("click", ".pic", function(){
     // code
  });
});
```

Comment: ...and make sure this is wrapped in `$(document).ready` or placed at the end of the document.